# Permissions for choosing tags in Cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

When trying to create a Cloudwatch dashboard I get "**You don't have permission to access tags and properties. Retry**".

What permissions does my IAM account have to have in order to be able to search and choose from tags and properties from Cloudwatch?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and adding this to AWS Policy hepled me

{
"Sid": "AllowReadingResourcesForTags",
"Effect": "Allow",
"Action": "tag:GetResources",
"Resource": "*"
}

Found it here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/cloudwatch/

Comment: This works for me, after I added  `CloudWatchFullAccess`, I still need to add this permission. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me thanks. 

1. I created a new Policy with the code from the example
2. I attached the new policy to the user Group

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest you to configure it via console.

1. Create a new role with `CloudWatchFullAccess`
2. Attach with required EC2 intance